# Ruby what does a line with just self and no .method do?

Tags: ruby, methods, return, self

I am trying to understand this Ruby code as a C# student who never programmed in Ruby. I have a good idea of what most of this does other than the line with just `self` on it. I would be grateful for any help in understanding. My best guess is that the `self` is used to call the classes initialize function but I'm not 100 % certain.

```
def link(cell, bidi=true)
  @links[cell] = true
  cell.link(self,false) if bidi
  self
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Every method returns something.  Either through an explicit `return` line, or if there's no explicit return, then the last executed line is returned.

In your example, `self` causes the method to return the object which is the receiver for the method... typically an instance of the class where the method was defined, although it could be inherited by other classes, or it could be from an included module (a mixin).

Comment: Thank you so much. So in this is the equivalent of `return this;` in C#.

Comment: I guess so.  What I know about C# could fit in a teeny little paper bag.  But if (for example) I saw `def Dog; def bark; puts "bow wow"; self; end; end` then I would expect that `dog = Dog.new; this_dog = dog.bark` then `this_dog` and `dog` would be referencing the same Dog object.